# Is there a way to initialize members of a struct without using a constructor?

Tags: c#, struct

I have a `struct` that contains two lists:

```
struct MonthData
{
   public List<DataRow> Frontline;
   public List<DataRow> Leadership;
}
```

However, I want to initialize both when the struct is created.  If I try:

```
struct MonthData
{
   public List<DataRow> Frontline = new List<DataRow>();
   public List<DataRow> Leadership = new List<DataRow>();
}
```

Then I get:

```
Error   23  'MonthData.Frontline': cannot have instance field initializers in structs
...
```

Since structs cannot have parameterless constructors, I can't just set this in a constructor either.  So far, I can only see the following options:

1. Initialize both properties when I create an instance of MonthData
2. Use a class instead of a struct
3. Create a constructor with a parameter and use that
4. Make getters and setters for the properties that initialize them
   lazily.

What is the recommended approach for this?  Right now, I'm thinking making this a class is the best idea.

Comment: Make it a class. Once you add reference types to a struct, it really isn't a value type anymore.

Comment: Is it really OK to make it a reference type (class) vs a value type (struct)? If it is, go ahead and make it a class.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense for this type to be a struct.

Comment: Making it a class adds another level of indirection, and if it just contains two classes, it is better to have it as value type, because the overhead of copying two addresses each time its passed somewhere is much less than one more indirection

Comment: structs are in the language for good reason.  there are plenty of cases where they are the appropriate choice when designing a new type. On the surface at least, this appears to be one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ought to use a class instead. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx):

> In general, classes are used to model more complex behavior, or data that is intended to be modified after a class object is created. Structs are best suited for small data structures that contain primarily data that is not intended to be modified after the struct is created.

Answer (score 7):

If you're just asking about syntax... try building and using a static factory instead... In general, structs should be used for things that are immutable, and a factory, (which calls a private constructor) is a better approach for an immutable type than using a public constructor.

```
  struct MonthData 
  {    
      public List<DataRow> Frontline;
      public List<DataRow> Leadership; 
      private MonthData(List<DataRow> frontLine = null, 
                        List<DataRow> leadership = null)
      { 
         Frontline = frontLine?? new List<DataRow>();
         Leadership = leadership?? new List<DataRow>();  
      }
      public static MonthData Factory(
          List<DataRow> frontLine= null, 
          List<DataRow> leadership= null)
      { return new MonthData(frontLine, leadership); }
  }
```

Comment: This is definitely an interesting approach.  As you mentioned, my object is not immutable though (it's more of a collection where things will be added to through-out its life) so perhaps a class is best.  +1 for the idea though.

Comment: I like the static factory method idea. However, you can't have instance field initializers in structs. So `public List<DataRow> FrontLine = new List<DataRow>()` isn't going to compile.

Comment: Also note that, even though the constructor you have written is private, the default parameterless constructor is still public.

Answer (score 7):

You're using reference types (`List<T>`) in your struct anyway, thus the usage of a struct as value type wouldn't make any sense to me. I'd just go with a class.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use `ImmutableArray<T>` and go with the builder method mentioned by @CharlesBretana.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with a constructor.  The CLR can and will create instances of structs simply be zero initializing the memory and avoid any ctor overhead.  However you can take advantage of this knowledge and create delay initialized properties which have the same observable effect.

For example:

```
struct MonthData {  
  private bool m_initialized;
  private List<DataRow> m_frontLine;
  private List<DataRow> m_leaderShip;

  public List<DataRow> FrontLine {
    get {
      EnsureInitialized(); 
      return m_frontLine;
    }
  }

  public List<DataRow> LeaderShip {
    get {
      EnsureInitialized(); 
      return m_leaderShip;
    }
  }

  void EnsureInitialized() {
    if (!m_initialized) {
      m_initialized = true;
      m_frontLine = new List<DataRow>();
      m_leaderShip = new List<DataRow>();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea I think doing something like this would be my second choice.  But it's such a simple object, I tend to agree with others here and think this should just be a class - especially since it just contains two reference types.

Comment: @MikeChristensen in general yes it should probably be a class.  My answer is more of a "if you get stuck in a corner and have to use a struct then do this"

Comment: Yea I think the factory approach and the lazy initialization approach are pretty cool - I will keep those in mind for future design challenges.

Comment: Mutable structs are *not* evil, but property getters which mutate the underlying struct in a semantically-meaningful way, *are*.  If an uninitialized MonthData is stored in something like a List, and code then the code repeatedly performs "MyMonths(3).LeaderShip.Add(someDataRow);", each invocation of the code will create a new List, add someDataRow to it, and then discard the newly-created list.

Comment: @supercat you're interpreting the code incorrectly.  The properties are delay initialized once not repeatedly initialized.

Comment: I'm interpreting the code the way the computer would. If MyMonths is a List<MonthData>, then MyMonths(3) will create a copy of one of the MonthData items therein. Accessing the LeaderShip property of that copy will cause a new List to be created and assigned to the m_leaderShip of that copy (not the one in the List). Once the LeaderShip property has been evaluated, the MonthData copy whose LeaderShip property was evaluated will be jettisoned. This is part of why Eric Lippert claims mutable structs are evil, although the real evil lies in property getters and methods which mutate "this".

Comment: @supercat ok yes in the case you return a copy then yes you get odd behavior.  Such is the life of mutable structs.  But the OP asked "how can this be done without a ctor" and this is a valid way to do it.  Answering with "never use mutable structs" is not helpful.

Comment: @JaredPar: I didn't say never to use mutable structs; if anything I'm one of their stronger advocates around here.  What I did say was that struct property getters shouldn't mutate the underlying struct, and I stand by that.  Most of the so-called "unexpected" behaviors of structs are in fact exactly the behaviors that should be expected of structs.  On the other hand, even knowing that MonthData is a struct, I wouldn't expect that "MyMonths[3].LeaderShip.Add(someDataRow)" could silently do nothing.  I'd expect that a NullReferenceException might occur if the struct was uninitialized, but ...

Comment: @JaredPar: ...I'd regard the fact that the operation succeeded without throwing an exception as an indication that any necessary initialization had occurred.  It seems much safer to require that structs be manually intialized before being stored in a list, and punish failure to do by throwing a NullReferenceException, than to require that they either be manually initialized or else have their LeaderShip property read, punishing failure by having update attempts silently do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice if the CLR had allowed a means of guaranteeing that things of structure type could have some initialization code run on them before they became visible to anything outside such code.  It would have been possible to do that, even when creating an array of a structure type, by having the CLR pass by reference all the individual elements of the array before a reference to the array itself was exposed anywhere.  Unfortunately, it would have led to an awkward situation if an exception were thrown during the creation of the array.  If the constructors didn't have any side effects, there would be no problem--simply discard the array and pretend that even the successfully-created objects never existed.  Constructors with side-effects, however, could cause some difficulties.

As it is, however, there's no way to initialize structures at construction, and consequently no nice way to achieve value-type semantics with objects requiring initialization.  Sorry.  Even if value-type semantics would be more appropriate for your type (as would be the case far more often than some would believe) you'll have to use a reference type if initialization is necessary.  Lazy initialization of structs doesn't really work.  For example, if one has a Dictionary<String, MonthData> called MyDict, repeated accesses to MyDict("George").FrontLine would each generate a new List.  Nasty.

Mutable structs are not evil; I am, if anything, one of their stronger advocates.  Nonetheless, there are some limitations in .net's handling of mutable structs, and there are thus many circumstances where value-type semantics would be appropriate, but .net limitations make it impossible to provide such semantics properly.